# CSS Fade in background image

Tags: html, css

The background of my page has a default background color, and a picture.

Here is my code :

HTML

```
<body background="https://www.switchbacktravel.com/sites/default/files/images/articles/Hiking%20photo.jpg" class="default-background" style="background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
```

CSS

```
.default-background {
  background-color: #17181a;
}
```

When the picture is heavy, or the user's internet connection slow, the default background color would appear first, and the picture second, when the picture is ready to load.

In that case, I want the picture to fade in smoothly, not brutally as it is the case now.

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cg45ygat/

My goal is to achieve the result (more or less) of WeTransfer background picture display : www.wetransfer.com

Is there a CSS animation way of doing this ?

Comment: A good way would be to use JavaScript to detect the image loading and remove .default-background from an element inside of background or use multiple background layers using a gradient with both stops being the same.

Comment: did you found a solution or still need ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(function(){
    var bgimage = new Image();      
    bgimage.src="https://www.switchbacktravel.com/sites/default/files/images/articles/Hiking%20photo.jpg";       
    $(".default-background").hide();     
    $(bgimage).load(function(){
        $(".default-background").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").fadeIn(2000); 
     }); 
});
```

```css
.default-background {
  background-color: #17181a;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="default-background fadeIn">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello brother hope my answer helped you some how

```
<body   class="default-background">
<div id="img">
<img id="pre-load" onload="fadeIn(this)" src="https://www.switchbacktravel.com/sites/default/files/images/articles/Hiking%20photo.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>
</body>
```

here is css

```
.default-background {
 background-color:#333;

 }
 #img{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;}
```

and brother here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg45ygat/6/)