# CSS Fade in background image when loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my page has a default background color and a background image.

I want the default background color to display until the image if fully loaded. Only when the image is loaded, it can fade in.

So far, I have been able to fade in the background image nicely, but the image fades in even if not completely loaded.

I want to achieve something similar to [WeTransfer](http://www.wetransfer.com/)

Here is my code :

HTML

```
<div id="container-background">

<div id="child-background">

  <p>Text</p>

</div> <!--container-background-->

</div> <!-- child-background-->
```

CSS

```
#container-background
{
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#child-background
{
  background: #17181a;
  transition: background 0.7s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.7s linear;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3804/11129952164_63075cdbe9_b.jpg);"
}
```

JS

```
$('#child-background').css('background', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dutn5vg9/)

Please help me fade in the background image only when it's loaded, and when not loaded yet, display the default background color.

Comment: bcause you set image in css url backround so it always load first before jquery code also

Comment: is this what you're trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/dutn5vg9/3/

Comment: I think this is same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171684/css-fade-in-background-image so I m taking this link image because in this code your image is not loaded.

Answer (score 2):

remove background image from css and try this :

```js
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3804/11129952164_63075cdbe9_b.jpg').load(function() {
     $('#child-background').css('background-image','url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3804/11129952164_63075cdbe9_b.jpg)');
    });
```

```css
#container-background
{
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#child-background
{
  background: #17181a;
  transition: background 0.7s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.7s linear;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-background">

<div id="child-background">

  <p>Text</p>

</div> <!--container-background-->

</div> <!-- child-background-->
```

Comment: you may add a full code so we can see the result :)

Comment: Thanks Rachele. I want to make the image appear when the image is loaded, not the window. All the content on my page is light, except the background image which is heavy and can take longer to load than the rest of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$(function(){
    var bgimage = new Image();      
    bgimage.src="https://www.switchbacktravel.com/sites/default/files/images/articles/Hiking%20photo.jpg";       
    $("#child-background").hide();     
    $(bgimage).load(function(){
        $("#child-background").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").fadeIn(2000); 
     }); 
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
#container-background
{  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background:#000;
}
#child-background
{
  background-color: #17181a;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  transition: background 0.7s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.7s linear;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%; 
  
}
p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-background">
  <div id="child-background">  
  <p>Text</p> 
</div> <!--container-background-->
</div> <!-- child-background-->
```